# Java - Mocking soap call with SOAPMessage request

Tags: java, unit-testing, soap, mockito, junit4

I am trying to mock a soap call which is returning null as response.

I have a java class where I am making a call to fedex web services to get the parsed address validated. Till here everything is fine, but when it comes to unit testing the issue arises. 
In test I am trying to mock the soap call by passing the same request parameters that is getting passed in actual java class but the mock is returning the response as null because of the request what I am passing is not same as what the soap call is expecting in java class.

Java class code (abc.java)-

```
SOAPMessage payload = getAddressRequestPayload();
SOAPMessage responseMessage = soapConnection.call(payload, settings.addressUrl());
```

Test code (junit4)-

```
SOAPMessage testResponse = getMockResponse();
SOAPMessage testPayload =  abc.getAddressRequestPayload();

when(mockSoapConnection.call(testPayload, settings.addressUrl())).thenReturn(testResponse);
```

Also I have tried getting the string xml request payload from java class and appending the new timestamp using fakeclock in test class to match both payloads but it seems to be different.
One way is give generic soapmessage class in when call like -

```
when(mockSoapConnection.call(any(SOAPMessage.class), anyString())).thenReturn(testResponse)
```

Then the test is passing, but that is not the correct way of checking a specific call.So how do I get to know the differnce between the payloads or is there any other way to mock the soap call??

Any help is appreciated.

Saurabh

Comment: Kind of confusing what are you asking, so it seems that with the last code you were able to make the test pass, but you want to test which value are you receiving in one of the parameters ?

Comment: My questions are if you are trying to verify that the string used as the second parameter is something specific or you are trying to test the test payload to have something on it?

Comment: First thing is I was trying to mock the soap call with the actual request payload but that is not a wise thing to do since the soapMessage instance will be different every time.

Comment: Hi SaurabhDwivedi, I'm facing some issue on the SOAP unit test and i found your post, would you mind to show me how your configure your unit test ? my unit test doesn't return content setup in mockito.when(), but it goes to the actually SOAPConnection.call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using any kind of matching framework like the one Mockito has, be careful to ensure that you really do have equality in the things you're setting up as expectations. If your `SOAPMessage` class for instance has no `equals` method then the mock will not work unless it gets the exact same instance of `testPayload` that's used in your test. If you're creating a new `SOAPMessage` in your class under test, and there's no equals method or the equals method would return "false", then it won't match and it won't work.

Generally if you're looking for complex functionality in a mock, it's easier to roll out your own class as a *test double*. Start by creating an implementation of the interface that checks for the relevant parameters and returns a response if they're present, and refactor it as you add more requirements.

It can be an inner class of the test, but since it crosses an integration / module boundary, you'll probably find that it's useful enough elsewhere to stick it in its own `testHelpers` folder or equivalent.

Comment: I think that is very informative suggestion, just came to the SoapMessage doesn't have any equality functions, the class creates a new instance msg every time it is called, so I have to convert both the request payloads to String and then compare it equals :)
So this is the only feasible solution to me as asserting the same request payload as the actual call is using.