# How to create unit test for SOAPConnection.call and mock SOAPConnection?

Tags: java, soap, mockito, junit4

Welcome to point out any mistake on my code, as this is my first time using SOAP and unit test.

I have a simple `SoapService` which create `SOAPConnection` and send the `SOAPMessage`

**SoapService.java**

```
public SOAPMessage sendSoapRequest(String url, String requestString) throws IOException, SOAPException {

    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection= soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();


    SOAPResponse soapResponse = soapConnection.call(getSoapMessage(requestString), url);
    soapConnection.close();

    return soapResponse;
}
```

and I have unit test class for `sendSoapRequest`

**SOAPServiceTest.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SoapServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    SoapService soapService;

    @Mock
    SOAPConnection mockSoapConnection;

    private SOAPMessage mockSoapResponse = mock(SOAPMessage.class);

    @Test
    public void testSendSoapMessage() throws IOException, SOAPException{

        when(mockSoapConnection.call(any(SOAPMessage.class), anyString())).thenReturn(mockSoapResponse);

        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapService.sendSoapRequest("http://test.com/test.asmx", "SampleSoapRequestString...");

        Assert.assertNotNull(soapResponse);
        Assert.assertEquals(soapResponse,mockSoapResponse);
    }
}
```

Referring the code

`when(mockSoapConnection.call(any(SOAPMessage.class),anyString())).thenReturn(mockSoapResponse);`

it should return `mockSoapResponse` but it didn't, it actually trying to send the `SOAPMessage` to the dummy url  `"http://test.com/test.asmx"` when comes to this line

`SOAPResponse soapResponse = soapConnection.call(getSoapMessage(requestString), url);`.

So my questions are

1. What is the correct way to have a unit test for 'sendSoapRequest`?
2. Is this the correct way to mock the `SOAPConnection` and define the behavior using `Mockito.when` ?
3. Am I missing any setup/configuration on the mock ?

I found a related question but it didn't show the complete setup:
[Java - Mocking soap call with SOAPMessage request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396905/java-mocking-soap-call-with-soapmessage-request)

Appreciate for any comment/idea/guide, because I'm really out of idea to get this work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAPConnection you are mocking is not the one inside your method, this is the reason what you are expecting doesn't happen.

More in detail, I think the lines you want to test are well known in documentation, so it is not so important to test them.
It is more important to test the input data handling to become input of your call (getSoapMessage(requestString) in your case) and the output data handling to become the output the caller expects (no-operation in your case, but maybe you should do something to return something that "talks the client language").

The logic of the calling can be tested in the code of the "other side".

Finally if you want to have a better code you can isolate all the soap related lines in a collaborator and mock it in order to test input and output handling.